# Best pattern for deciding presentation logic of UIViewControllers in a navigation flow

Tags: ios, architecture

I have a group of UIViewControllers in a navigation structure and I want there to be several different combinations in the order they are presented. Should I place this logic in the parent UINavigationController, or a separate object passed down to the view controllers on load? I'm struggling to find the best pattern.

Comment: would you specify - should you know their order from the start, or order can be changed dynamically according to the logic?

Comment: give some examples of what the order logic is. does it make sense for one thing to own it, or is it distributed and variable, depending on what inputs?

Comment: I would have a few sets of known order. These sets would ideally be specified in a json.